# Existences of the infimum implies the existence of another infimum

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $A$ is non empty subset of real numbers. Define $B=\{2x: x\in A\}$. Show that
$$\inf(B)=2\inf(A)$$

I believe that I can prove that the equality is true but I can't find a simple way of showing that if $\inf(a)$ exists then $\inf(B)$ exists and vice versa. (Note I know I have to do this because $A$ is not necessarily bounded from above nor below).

Can I get some help on this?

Comment: identify the bijection between the 2 full ordered sets and recall that a product by a positive number ( here 2 ) conserves the order

Comment: So let $f:A\to B$. Hence $f(x)=2x$ for $x\in A$.And the other direction is $g:B\to A$, $g(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}x$ for $x\in B$. Hence both functions are bijections because the inverse function exists. But how does this show that the infimums exists?

Comment: you have not to show that they exist but that if the first exists then the second too ( and reciprocally )

Comment: Infimums of nonempty sets always exist (possibly being $-\infty$).  One way is to show $\leq$ and $\geq$.  For example, for any $a \in A$ we know $2a \in B$ and so $2a \geq \inf(B)$.

Comment: @Michael That is enough to should exists of inf(B)?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown : What do you mean by "exists"?  Also, what happens if you divide my last inequality by 2?

Comment: That showed in the previous comment shows "if $\inf(a)$ exists then $\inf(b)$ exists"

Comment: @UsernameUnknown : I am having trouble understanding you.  I do not know what you mean by "exists."  Do you mean "finite"? Also, where does your sentence "if $\inf(a)$ exists then $\inf(b)$ exists" come from, in relation to some previous comment (which previous comment?)  And what happens if you divide my inequality by 2?

Comment: That was a hint that was given for the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44841/discussion-between-michael-and-username-unknown).

Answer (score 1):

We will first show that $2\inf(A)$ is a lower bound for $B$. Consider $y \in B$. We can write $y =2x$ for some $x \in A$. Notice since $\inf(A) \leq x$ then $2\inf(A) \leq 2x =y$. This shows that $2\inf(A)$ is a lower bound for $B$.

Now we need to show that it's the greatest lower bound. Suppose there was a greater lower bound $L$. We can write $L = 2\inf(A) + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon >0$. Notice that since $\inf(A)+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon$ is bigger than the greatest upper bound for $A$, then there exists an $x \in A$ such that $x < \inf(A)+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon$. This implies $2x < 2\inf(A)+\epsilon = L$. Setting $y=2x$, notice that $y\in B$ and we have $y < L$, a contradiction since $L$ is a lower bound of $B$. That means that $2\inf(A)$ is the greatest lower bound of $B$ and hence the infimum of $B$.